# Boolean 1 and 0 not searchable on yajra laravel-datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatable

I have this boolean data of 1 = 'Active' and 0 = 'Inactive'.

I successfully rendered it to the datatable, but the problem if I trying to search 'Active' or 'Inactive' it shows No matching records found.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Here is my datatable js code

```
columns: [
            { data: 'photo', name: 'photo' },
            { data: 'full_name', name: 'full_name' },
            { data: 'm_lname', name: 'm_lname'},
            { data: 'm_fname', name: 'm_fname'},
            { data: 'm_mname', name: 'm_mname'},
            { data: 'm_gender', name: 'm_gender' },
            { data: 'm_datebaptized', name: 'm_datebaptized' },
            { data: 'm_isactive', name: 'm_isactive',
            render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
               return data ? "Active" : "Inactive" ;
            }
        },

            { data: 'action', name: 'action' },

        ],columnDefs: [
            { targets: [2,3,4], visible: false},
            { targets: '_all', visible: true },
            { searchable: true, targets: '_all'},
            { searchable: false, targets: [0,8]},
            { orderData: 2, targets: 1 },
        ],
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to move mapping to

```
return datatables()->of(User::all()->map(function ($item) {
    $item->m_isactive = $item->m_isactive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
    return $item;
})->toJson();
```

and delete

```
render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
               return data ? "Active" : "Inactive" ;
            }
```